# Question. oracle_fdw - Import foreign schema limit to synonym?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, oracle-fdw

oracle_fdw - ‎Is it possible in PostgreSQL to import foreign schema with a limit to synonym - as in the attached image?
ㅤ

For example, this not working (limit to synonym):

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA "UserA" LIMIT TO (A_SYNONYM) FROM SERVER oracledb INTO public;
```

but works when I try to import foreign schemat limit to view or table:

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA "UserB" LIMIT TO (B_VIEW) FROM SERVER oracledb INTO public;
```

‎
So, it is possible to use synonyms in import foreign schema "LIMIT TO ()"?

‎

[image: This image explains what I mean]

Answer (score 0):

When processing `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`, oracle_fdw searches through the Oracle view `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` in Oracle. According to the Oracle documentation

> `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` describes the columns of the tables, views, and clusters accessible to the current user.

That sounds like synonyms won't be listed. You can easily test that by omitting the `LIMIT TO` clause. If foreign tables for synonyms are not created, you have a proof.

As a workaround, you could import those tables from the schemas where they really reside.